# How to return the scene view camera to the default view

Tags: unity, camera, perspective, editors

By the "scene view camera" I don't mean a `GameObject` with a `Camera` component, I mean the camera used to draw the Scene window in the Unity editor, controlled by this "Scene Gizmo" widget:

[image: Camera controls stick]

The default view shows an almost isometric perspective, where all three X Y Z axes are visible.

But when I clicked the green Y cone, my view changed to look straight down the Y axis, and I can't seem to return to the 3-axis view.

Clicking the other cones on this widget just switchest to look along the X or Z axis instead, and clicking the cube in the middle or the "Top" label just toggles between orthographic and perspective projection.

How can I get back to the default 3-axis view?

Comment: You may have misclicked and gone into 2D view. If you click the cube in the center, that will take you back to 3D mode.

Comment: no, it's definitely in 3d mode. I tried switching _to_ 2d mode to see if I could find an option, but then I switched back to 3d mode.

Comment: Right-click-hold and move the mouse. That will rotate. Middle-click-hold will pan. If you don't have a middle click, in the toolbar (top left) is a hand icon. Click that, then left mouse pans (right mouse still rotates).

Comment: I'm using one of the new MacBook Pro laptops with the touchbar. The right click on these things is horrible. I don't buy into the trend of deprecating right click buttons, but that's a tangent. I am familiar with these things you mention, but I was hoping there was a button to jump to this view like there is for the x,y,z axes, since I can get by decently with just a left click button most of the time.

Comment: Hold alt while in the pan mode (the toolbar Hand icon). Then left-click becomes rotate. I'm not entirely sure what modifier key the Windows alt maps to on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Orthographic/perspective camera in the Scene View is toggled by clicking the text underneath the X/Y/Z widget (which says 'Top' in your screenshot).

Perspective view will show converging lines there, while isometric view will show parallel lines.

Comment: I think you mean "orthographic" not "isometric" — Isometric projection is an orthographic projection from particular viewing directions that foreshorten the three axes equally (unlike, say, a pure side-on or top-down orthographic view that flattens one axis to zero)

Answer (score 1):

Remember to check the documentation for the tools you're using! In this case, the [Scene View Navigation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SceneViewNavigation.html) page explains how to control the scene view camera:

> If your Scene view is in an awkward viewpoint (upside-down, or just an angle you find confusing), **Shift-click the cube** at the centre of the Scene Gizmo to get back to a Perspective view with an angle that is looking at the Scene from the side and slightly from above.

Other ways to adjust the view angle include:

> **Orbit**
>
> Hold **Alt** (Windows) or **Option** (macOS), and left-click and drag to orbit the Camera around the current pivot point.
>
> This option is not available in 2D mode, because the view is orthographic.

and

> **Flythrough mode**
>
> Use the Flythrough mode
> to navigate the Scene view by flying around in first-person, similar to how you would navigate in many games:
>
> - Click and hold the **right mouse button**.
> - Move the view around using the mouse, the WASD keys to move left/right/forward/backward, and the Q and E keys to move up and down.
> - Hold down Shift to move faster.